# I want to remove wordpress shortcodes from html content in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to remove shortcodes which comes from WordPress API, 
Here is the sample content

[et_pb_section bb_built=”1″][et_pb_row][et_pb_column type=”4_4″][et_pb_text _builder_version=”3.4.1″]

#### The Pro’s of the Gewa Air case are:

light weight: 1.7 kg

compact, certainly if you take the violin shaped version

durable and strong

beautiful design

high end finish

I want to remove text between [* some text *]

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSError *error;
NSString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[_postData valueForKey:@"content"] valueForKey:@"rendered"]];

NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *text = nil;
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    // find start of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"[" intoString:NULL];
    // find end of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"]" intoString:&text];
    // replace the found tag with a space
    //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"%@]",text] withString:@""];
 }
```